# PnP Provisioning Template Object reference not set to instance

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, pnp-powershell, pnp-provisioning

Ok I am trying to apply a Provisioning template to a site and I keep getting the error

"Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Ive been following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine) tutorial on microsoft.

Once I get to the Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path i get the error above. Any ideas?

Note: Running the latest version of SharePointPnPPowerShellOnlien 3.24.2008.1

Comment: Can you check the trace log after what step is ti failing?

Comment: Im getting two errors:

[Site Security] [16] [Information] Failed to EnsureUser c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider

Comment: [OfficeDevPnP.Core] [0] [Error] ExecuteQuery threw following exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The specified user

Answer (score 0):

The template is trying to find **federateddirectoryclaimprovider**  user for applying permissions to it, but is not able to find this user in Site. To avoid this you can execute the `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate` command with `-ExcludeHandlers SiteSecurity` switch by doing so it will not apply permissions to users aganist any SharePoint groups being created.

Comment: Still getting the two errors above, I noticed in the server error details that I have the error

Error during webhook add/update: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID